# Executable(.exe) File Analysis Software?

Tags: exe, executable, sandbox

Is there a software that does the following?

Runs the executable in a protected environment.
Logs the details of the files the executable accesses or creates or modifies.
Creates before and after copies of such files so that these can be analysed.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for a sandbox.

Comment: Post that kind of question here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a software recommendation